# Get a list of apps which can play music

Tags: android

I want to get a list of apps which can play music.
I tried this code but it return me an empty list :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1"); 
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setType("audio/*");
List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo rInfo : apps) {
    //process list here
}
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2):

> Get a list of apps which can play music

You cannot really. App does not expose it features music playing capabilities.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to get a list of apps which use MediaPlayer ?

Comment: No. And MediaPlayer is not the only way to play media

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - Is this still true?